# Change spring security default login url: spring-security-login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Dose anyone knows how I can change spring security default login url: spring-security-login?
I know that there is an attribute with form-login tag, named login-processing-url, but I don't want to have custom login page. Just I want to change the login url to something like "login.htm".

It seems that the login-processing-url attribute just works when you have specified a custom login form.

I have tried this:

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/accessDenied.htm" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/redirect.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login.htm" />
    <logout/>       
</http>
```

but it doesn't work. Still it shows "spring-security-login" as login url.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `login-page`:

```
<form-login login-page="/login.htm" />
```

Comment: But I don't want to have a custom login page, just want to rename login url from spring-security-login to login.htm.